# How to register a class for use it in a QWebChannel signal in Qt

Tags: c++, json, qt, communication, qmetatype

Im using QT 5 with a WebChannel to communicate with a HTML Page.
I successfully able to communicate texts and strings. however i woud like to communicate some points data.

the official documentation says

> "No manual message passing and serialization of data is required,"
>    http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html

When i try to send a object or an array, instead of a string, the application throw this message:

> Don't know how to handle 'data', use qRegisterMetaType to register it.

How can I emit a signal with a Point class instead of a string object? Or to serialize a class to a string.

This is the object that i would like to send to my HTML

Point class

```
class MyData{
public :
    int x,y,z;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyData)
```

Map class

```
class MyMap : public QObject{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyMap ();

signals:
    updateText(const QString &text); // registered
    updateData(MyData &data); //   Don't know how to handle 'data', use qRegisterMetaType to register it.

public slots:
    receiveText(const QString &text);
};
```

and the main code

```
qRegisterMetaType<MyData>();

// setup the channel
QWebChannel channel;
QObject::connect(&clientWrapper, &WebSocketClientWrapper::clientConnected, &channel, &QWebChannel::connectTo);

// setup the dialog and publish it to the QWebChannel
channel.registerObject(QStringLiteral("map"), &map);

map.updateText("text");

MyData data;
data.x=10;
data.y=12;
data.z=13;
map.updateData(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1):

> To use the type T in QVariant, using Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() is
>   sufficient. To use the type T in queued signal and slot connections,
>   qRegisterMetaType() must be called before the first connection is
>   established.

In my own code, I use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` for classes I want to store in a `QVariant` (this macro has to by put at global scope). And I `qRegisterMetaType<T>()` for classes I want to be passed to signals/slots (this function has to be called before the signal.slot connection is made). I never had to call both if using only one feature.

So, for your example, this should work:

```
qRegisterMetaType<MyData>( "MyData" );
// then, form here, you can connect `updateData(MyData)` signal to any slot taking a MyData parameter
```

For signal/slot declaration:

- If `qRegisterMetaType` was not called, you can only use signal/slot passing `MyData` by reference or pointer (declare the `signal` as `void updateData(MyData& data);` or `void updateData(MyData* data);`). Then, you must be very careful if doing asynchonous connection (like `Qt::QueuedConnection`) because, as the `slot` will be executed "later", you must guarantee that object reference remains valid untill the `slot` gets executed after you emited the `signal`.
- If `qRegisterMetaType` was called, you can use signal/slot passing `MyData` by copy (declare the `signal` as `void updateData(MyData data);`). And it's safe to do asynchonous connection with those objects passed by copy as Qt is able to serialize the object (meaning that if the `slot` is executed "later" it will in the end be called with a brand new `MyData` object copied from the original one you emited the signal with....without `qRegisterMetaType` being called, Qt is unable to do this "copy").

Make sure `MyData` declaration is known when you do this (no forward declaration).

Note also that not all classes/structs can be registered this way, they must have:

> a public default constructor, a public copy constructor, and a public destructor

It's the case for your `MyData` class (default ones are OK), so it should work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a line somewhere before your slot like this:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Block>();
```

What you are doing is telling the Meta Object Compiler (MOC) all about your class and how to pass it around. Further reading can be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/custom-types.html) which discusses this problem in much more detail, and gives examples.

Comment: adding this line i got: \include\QtCore\qglobal.h:703: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'QStaticAssertFailure<false>'
     enum {Q_STATIC_ASSERT_PRIVATE_JOIN(q_static_assert_result, __COUNTER__) = sizeof(QStaticAssertFailure<!!(Condition)>)}
                                                                                     ^

Comment: @DanielSantos MyData class is not a QObject, it need Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro.

Comment: I added this (edited on question), however i get the same output (Don't know how to handle 'data', use qRegisterMetaType to register it.) and the channel sends a "NULL" text

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pass a string representation of a type name as a parameter to the function

```
qRegisterMetaType<MyData>("MyData");
```